# Javascript - simple exercises

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math

I have a task to write a function `getEvenAverage`, which should take only one argument - array. This function should `return` an average value of even numbers from this array. If in the array there aren't any even numbers the function should return `null`.

I'd really appreciate any feedback :-)

```
function getEvenAverage(tab) {
  {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(tab[i], 10);
      }
      var avg = sum / tab.length;
    } else
      console.log('null');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your function is not returning anything

Comment: I think you are missing something in your example? there are too many curly brackets (`{` `}`)

Comment: Don't use `var`, use `let` instead! (It will directly show you some of the errors youve made)

Comment: @emil a few additional block statements are indeed confusing, but they don't change the way the code works :)

Answer (score 3):

You say you need to return something, so `return` it. Also move your `if` statement inside your `for` loop, and fix a few other syntax errors. And as pointed out in the comments, you should divide `sum` by the number of even numbers to get your `avg`:

```js
function getEvenAverage(tab) {
  var sum = 0;
  var evens = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      sum += parseInt(tab[i], 10);
      evens++;
    } 
  }
  if (evens == 0) {
    console.log("null");
    return null;
  } else {
    var avg = sum / evens;
    return avg;
  }
}

console.log(getEvenAverage([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: i think you should not divide on tab.length, rather on how many even numbers there were

Comment: Oh yes, my bad @giorgim.

Comment: Fixed now @giorgim, any better?

Comment: I agree, I was just sticking to the OP's idea of what their code should do.

Comment: I think if I read OP's question correct you are missing one thing he says that if in the whole array there is no even number it should return null. doesn't that mean that instead of your else return null. you should set another if outside the for loop. if evens = 0 return null? cause now you also return a null because there is 1 non even number though there is an even one in the array

Comment: Yes @mrdeadsven, I'll add that.

Comment: You made a mistake here. You check the position and not the value in that position in your if. You should check `i % 2 === 0`. And it's better to check if the type of the input is an array, and then use a loop on it.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it with the array reduce, with a single array traversal

```js
const reducer = (acc, val) => {
  let {
    sum,
    count
  } = acc;
  return (val % 2 === 0 ? {
    sum: sum + val,
    count: count + 1
  } : acc);
};

const getEvenAverage = (input) => {
  const initialValue = {
    sum: 0,
    count: 0
  };
  const output = input.reduce(reducer, initialValue);

  if (output.count === 0) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return output.sum / output.count;
  }
};

console.log(getEvenAverage([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct function.

```
function getEvenAverage(tab) {
    if (!Array.isArray(tab)) return null;

    let sum = 0, count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
      if (tab[i] % 2 === 0) {
        sum += parseInt(tab[i]);
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count > 0 ? (sum / count) : null;
}
```

Wish You happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function,

```js
function getEvenAverage(tab) {
        var numberOfEvens = 0;
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
             if(tab[i]%2 == 0 ){
                 numberOfEvens++;
                 sum += tab[i];
             }
        }
        if(numberOfEvens == 0)return null;
        return sum/numberOfEvens;
    }
    
    console.log(getEvenAverage([0,1,2,3,4,5]))
    console.log(getEvenAverage([1,2,3,4,5]))
    console.log(getEvenAverage([0,1,11,3,4,5]))
    console.log(getEvenAverage([1,5,3]))
```

Comment: You get a wrong result for the last example array. 0 is an even number and the average should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need only the even numbers, so first [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array into a new array, then sum all the numbers (using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) or a for loop) and divide by its length.

```js
function getEvenAverage(array) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) return null; // not a must if you're sure you pass an array
  var evenArray = array.filter(function(value) {
    return value % 2 === 0
  });
  if (evenArray.length === 0) return null;
  var evenSum = evenArray.reduce(function(total, current) {
    return total + current;
  });
  var evenAvg = evenSum / evenArray.length;
  return evenAvg;
}

console.log(getEvenAverage("not an array"));
console.log(getEvenAverage([1,3,7])); // no even numbers
console.log(getEvenAverage([1,2,3])); // single even number
console.log(getEvenAverage([2,2,2])); // only even numbers
console.log(getEvenAverage([1,2,3,10,18])); // bigger array
console.log(getEvenAverage([0,1])); // 0 is also even
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than using a for loop, you can utilize filter and reduce Array methods.

```js
function getEvenAverage(arr) {
  const newArr = arr.filter(number => number % 2 === 0);
  return newArr.length > 0 ? newArr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num) / newArr.length : null;
}

console.log(getEvenAverage([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(getEvenAverage([1, 3, 5, 7]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getEvenAverage(arr){
  var evenNumbers = []; // we use an array to hold all of our evenNumbers
  for  (var el of arr){ // we loop over the received array to check the received
    if(el % 2 !=0){ // if the number is even
      evenNumbers.push(el); // we add it to our evenNumbers array
    }
  }
  if(evenNumbers.length == 0){ // when we have no even Number
    return false; // we then return false
  }
  else{
    // the next block of code calculates the average of the even values
    return evenNumbers.reduce((pv,cv) => pv+cv,0)/evenNumbers.length;
  }
}

var evenNumbers = [4,2,3,6,5,9];
getEvenAverage(evenNumbers); // returns 5.666666666666667
getEvenAverage([2,4,6,8]); // returns false
```